# Python converting UINT8

Tags: python, j1939

I have some canbus string data (unit8) like: data: [24, 4, 0, 0, 191, 9, 146, 9]

When I try to capture this data and print on the console it looks like ascii.

```
payload = [x for x in data.data]
print payload
>>>['\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x02', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00']
```

How do I get this data back to:
[24, 4, 0, 0, 191, 9, 146, 9]

Matt

Comment: What type is `data.data` and why are you iterating over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn it into a `bytearray`.

```
>>> bytearray('abc')
bytearray(b'abc')
>>> bytearray('abc')[1]
98
```

Comment: Yes, that worked.  I used payload = bytearray(data.data) then print [x for x in payload]   it prints [24, 4, 0, 0, 191, 9, 146, 9]

Comment: @Droter if you feel that solved your problem, you should accept it as the correct answer.